# Can spring security specify different UserDetailsService instances for different paths?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, java-8

The following code is wrong, but I hope that one day it will be supported.

Of course, I must first thank the developers of spring security and related components. Thank you for allowing us to write safe software so easily.

```java
@Configuration
class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("AdminerDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService adminerDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("UserDetailsService")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/backend-admin/**").hasRole("REGULAR")
                .userDetailsService(adminerDetailsService)
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/admin")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/backend-ContentCentre/**").hasRole("NORMAL")
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login/user")
                .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

The above code basically shows my intention. Users accessing `/backend-ContentCentre` use different `UserDetailService` implementation from that for accessing `/backend-admin`. How should I configure to achieve this target?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have them into separate configurations. Still, they must be annotated with `@Order` :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SimpleSecurityConfiguration {

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public static class AdminConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/backend-admin/**")
                .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .login(login -> login
                    .loginUrl("/login/admin")
                );
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
            auth.userDetailsService(adminDetailsService);
        }
    }


    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public static class AdminConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/backend-user/**")
                .authorizeRequests(authz -> authz.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .login(login -> login
                    .loginUrl("/login/user")
                );
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
            auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the use of lambda for constructing the login and the authorizations. Also, the code provided in the question **doesn't permit to distinguish which userService to use for each path**